# Custom ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom AngularJS repeat directive, because ngRepeat doesn't fit my needs in this particular case, where I'm creating a sort of templating language based on angular directives, and I can't afford to freely create DOM elements.

In particular, these are the problems I have with ngRepeat and I'm trying to solve:

- I need the repeater element to be the parent of the elements being repeated
- the repeated elements have different templates, and I can't use wrapper elements or ngSwitches to provide different markup

I have created a custom directive that should:

- empty the repeater DOM element
- watch the current scope and at each call loop through an array, create a new DOM element per iteration, and compile the element with a childscope
- keep the whole thing bind to the model

The problem with this approach is that I'm creating an infinite loop (I get the 10 $digest error) because I'm modifying the scope (creating the child scope) at each scope $watch fn call.

How can I approach this problem ? I tried looking at the ngRepeat source but that's pretty difficult to understand for me...

**Sidequestion:** A minor (for now) problem would be the performance of re-rendering the whole thing each time the scope is modified... How difficult would be to implement different actions for array's adding, removal and update of items ?

Comment: First, are you sure that ngRepeat is inadequate?  A repeated element could be a parent of other elements: `<div ng-repeat="f in foos"><span>child</span></div>`.  Why can't you use ngSwitch?  It is designed to provide different templates.  It sounds like you are going to re-write a lot of functionality that has already been extensively optimized.  I'm not saying your question is somehow invalid; I'm just making sure you understand that AngularJS has already thought about how to do what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I've already implemented the features I need using ngRepeat and ngSwitch, but I'm looking for another solution since this has the problem that extra markup is required to make it work. The templates are supplied by the users, so I cannot predict exactly what kind of tags the app will deal with, and I need to stick with the provided markup as much as possible, for the simple reason that in most cases users will supply tables (it's an html email editor). I cannot (for example) wrap a <tr> tag with <div>, because the browser will move the div outside of the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding custom element to ngRepeat list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420147/adding-custom-element-to-ngrepeat-list)